# Быстрый обмен данными клиента с сервером

Tags: mysql, разработка-игр, php, ajax, javascript

**Всем привет!**

В процессе создания одного приложения( игры ) на JS возникла необходимость моментального обмена данными с сервером( данные, например, это текущая позиция на игровом поле, которая часто меняется ), которые потом должны быть также быстро прочитаны другими клиентами. Я пробовал реализовать это через Ajax запрос к PHP-хэндлеру на сервере. Сначала попробовал асинхронный запрос - безумная задержка( что логично )!  Затем не асинхронный - все игровые процессы начали "подвисать"( ведь последующий JS код в таком случае выполнится лишь после того, как данные получены от сервера ). В общем, я нахожусь в безвыходной ситуации... Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли способ моментального обмена данными сервером? Как реализован моментальный обмен данными в других сетевых играх, в которых изменение различных игровых свойств достаточно частое?

**Спасибо =)**

Comment: websockets например, событийный сервер (не php обычно)

Comment: Суть в том, чтобы была поддержка динамических запросов. С сокетами из JS это возможно?

Comment: @0xFFh да, сокеты - самое то. Отклик в пределах играбельности.

Comment: @eicto, @lampa, ок, раз сокеты - это единственный выход, то не могли бы вы мне дать ссылку на доки, где об этом можно максимально подробно узнать. И, да, если событийный сервер обычно пишется не на PHP, то на чем же?

Comment: @0xFFh для начала википедию: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket
Я от них отталкивался. Если node.js, то ни в коем случае не использовать socket.io из-за его монструозности. Я бы предпочел https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node

Comment: что ж, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо взаимодействие в реальном времени, а не асинхронность.
Протокол HTTP, через который осуществляется взаимодействие по своей природе основан на системе запрос-ответ, и не предназначен для канального соединения, то есть когда между абоннентами организуется постоянный канал.

Как написано выше использовать websockets, но он пока ещё не у всех есть (я имею виду на клиенте).

Есть ещё технология comet - когда поверх http эмулируют канальное соединение.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я уже со всем этим разобрался. Самое подходящее решение - технология сокетов, т.е открытый двусторонний канал передачи данных. Это можно сделать, например, используя NodeJS на выделенном сервере.

Comment: Раз уж вы с этим разобрались, напишите по подробней что использовали на клиенте и на сервере, может куски кода. Если поддержка деградации, когда клиент не поддерживает сокеты?

Answer (score 0):

Ну вообще-то вам нужна асинхронная отправка.
Ибо асинхронный запрос как раз тем и асинхронен, что не подвешивает выполнение программы, пока не выполнится, а дает программе исполняться дальше, по завершению вызвав функцию-callback.
Если скорости асинхронного запроса XHttpRequest вам не хватает, то тогда даже и не знаю что вам можно предложить.
Вот кстати немного инфы по вашему запросу:
[Ajax requests/responses: how to make them lightning fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403690/ajax-requests-responses-how-to-make-them-lightning-fast)

И еще немного по теме:
[How to make fast, lightweight, economic online chat with PHP + JS + (MySQL?) + (AJAX?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370591/how-to-make-fast-lightweight-economic-online-chat-with-php-js-mysql?rq=1)

Comment: Вряд ли это актуально для моего асинхронного запроса, который, кстати говоря, выполняется раз в 0.01 секунды! Это плохо как для сервера, так и для клиента.